# Get the position in a ArrayList from a button choice

Tags: android, arraylist

I'm trying to get the position of the ArrayList when the user click on a button. For exemple, if the user click button number 3, I need to get the position 2 of the List).

I have put the question with some choices, in the ArrayList, the button are also created but actually whatever is the choice of he User i get the position 0.

Question.java :

```
public Question(String question, List<String> choiceList, int answerIndex) 
{
    this.setQuestion(question);
    this.setChoiceList(choiceList);
    this.setAnswerIndex(answerIndex);
}

//and all the get and set
```

GameActivity :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    System.out.println("GameActivity::onCreate()");

    mQuestionBank = this.generateQuestions();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(BUNDLE_STATE_SCORE);
        mNumberOfQuestions = 
    savedInstanceState.getInt(BUNDLE_STATE_QUESTION);
    } else {
        String bar1 = "TheShamrock";
        String bar2 = "Ninkasi";
        String bar3 = "CrazyDog";
        mNumberOfQuestions = 4;
    }

    mEnableTouchEvents = true;

    // Wire widgets
    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) 
    findViewById(R.id.activity_game_question_text);
    mAnswerButton1 = (Button) 
    findViewById(R.id.activity_game_answer1_btn);
    mAnswerButton2 = (Button) 
    findViewById(R.id.activity_game_answer2_btn);
    mAnswerButton3 = (Button) f 
    findViewById(R.id.activity_game_answer3_btn);
    mAnswerButton4 = (Button) 
    findViewById(R.id.activity_game_answer4_btn);

    // Use the tag property to 'name' the buttons
    mAnswerButton1.setTag(0);
    mAnswerButton2.setTag(1);
    mAnswerButton3.setTag(2);
    mAnswerButton4.setTag(3);

    mAnswerButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
    mAnswerButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
    mAnswerButton3.setOnClickListener(this);
    mAnswerButton4.setOnClickListener(this);

    mCurrentQuestion = mQuestionBank.getQuestion();
    this.displayQuestion(mCurrentQuestion);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int responseIndex = (int) v.getTag();

    mEnableTouchEvents = false;

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mEnableTouchEvents = true;

            // If this is the last question, ends the game.
            // Else, display the next question.
            if (--mNumberOfQuestions == 0) {
                // End the game
                endGame();
            } else {
                mCurrentQuestion = mQuestionBank.getQuestion();
                displayQuestion(mCurrentQuestion);
            }
        }
    }, 1000); // LENGTH_SHORT is usually 1 second long
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return mEnableTouchEvents && super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}



 private QuestionBank generateQuestions() {
    Question question1 = new Question("Biere is important ?", 
     Arrays.asList("Yes", "Bof", "NO","idk"), 0);

    index.add(question1.getAnswerIndex());
    Log.i("test", String.valueOf(question1.getAnswerIndex()));
}
```

So like I say, if at the question I click on the button "NO" i need to retrieve the position 2. Or if I click on "Yes", i need the position 0.

I'm stuck ... have you guys have any idea ?

Comment: I honestly think you need to rethink your architecture. This would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question. Where are you are getting the answer?
The answer is in the `onClick` event.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int responseIndex = (int) v.getTag();   // this is the answer
```

But you never use `responseIndex` anywhere...